# Override swift protocol property to optional

Tags: ios, swift, xml, codable, xmlmapper

I am using this library, https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper.

It contains protocol,

```
public protocol XMLBaseMappable {
    var nodeName: String! { get set }
}
```

I would like to make this `nodeName` optional for my struct/classes implementing it, like

```
public protocol CustomXMLBaseMappable {
    var nodeName: String? { return "default" }

    //I don't want struct/classes using it, implements `nodeName`.
}
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: No You can't change the definition of protocol.

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to do this? I am asking this because the implementation of this property is very important for the correct functioning of the library.

Comment: @gcharita In my case, I have to Encode class/struct of a third-party library, which are there using Pods. And since the extension cannot contain stored-property, `nodeName` is creating trouble for me. Help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existence of this property in `XMLBaseMappable` protocol is crucial in order to function correctly the whole library.

Having said that, you can't omit the implementation of this property in your structs and classes but you can "hide" it in a super class. Using this:

```
class BasicXMLMappable: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    required init(map: XMLMap) {

    }

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {

    }
}
```

You can have `XMLMappable` objects that extends `BasicXMLMappable` and they don't have to implement `nodeName` property:

```
class TestBasicXMLMappable: BasicXMLMappable {

    // Your custom properties

    required init(map: XMLMap) {
        super.init(map: map)
    }

    override func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        // Map your custom properties
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
As of version 1.5.1 you can use `XMLStaticMappable` for implementing `XMLMapper` in an extension. For example:

```
class CustomClass {
    var property: String?
}

extension CustomClass: XMLStaticMappable {
    var nodeName: String! {
        get {
            return "default"
        }
        set(newValue) {

        }
    }

    static func objectForMapping(map: XMLMap) -> XMLBaseMappable? {
        // Initialize CustomClass somehow
        return CustomClass()
    }

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        property <- map["property"]
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought of the same implementation, what you have suggested. But in my case, I have to `Encode` class/struct of a third-party library, which are there using Pods. And since, the extension cannot contain stored-property, `nodeName` is creating trouble for me. Help !!

Comment: There is a workaround for this but then you will have problem implementing the `required init(map:)` specified by `XMLMappable` protocol as extension are not able to do this either. (you cannot implement directly `XMLBaseMappable`) I am releasing right now a new version of the pod that adds the missing `XMLStaticMappable` protocol and I will update my post.

Comment: I am looking into commits you are making. One suggestion, instead of adding `nodeName` into protocol & making in complex, why don't you follow approach of using default-parameter, like default `nodeName` will be `root` & if user wants to change it he can do so, in Mappable methods like `toXMLString(with rootKey: String = "default-root")`. This approach will simplify its usability.

Comment: I already updated my answer. Did you had any luck implementing the `XMLStaticMappable` protocol with the latest version of the pod?  About your suggestion with `nodeName`, I believe I added it in the `XMLBaseMappable` protocol not only to know the root element's name, but to also solve an issue that occurred in the serialization of `Array<XMLMappable>` properties. However, I will consider improving it somehow. Thank you.

Comment: I liked the solution `XMLStaticMappable`, but in my case, as I said, I have to encode the third party classes & they are many in number (like 20+). Subclassing all of them in my project doesn't sound to be a good approach. And even few are structures. So, as of now, I have commented out `nodeName` from the protocol in your library. And using it further. I know, it's not the best way, as you mentioned it was there to overcome an issue. But, let's see. I wish you to get rid of `nodeName`, as you have written a brilliant library. 

Comment: Thank you. Excuse me for insisting, but you don't need to subclass all the third party classes. However, you need to create an extension for every one of them. You probably already done that to implement `mapping(map:)` function of `XMLBaseMappable` protocol. If this is the case you just need to add the `var nodeName: String! { get { return "default" } set(newValue) { } }` part of my answer, in those extensions.

Comment: Bingo !! This is great. Thanks a ton, Man !! 

Answer (score 0):

You can't override the original protocol, but you could manually change it like that:

```
@objc protocol XMLBaseMappable {
    @objc optional var nodeName: String! { get set }
}
```

or leave it as it is, and create your custom protocol

```
@objc protocol CustomXMLBaseMappable {
    @objc optional var nodeName: String! { get set }
}
```